# I am facing a problem when I update data to mysql using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am facing a problem when I update data in mysql using jquery.

When I update "orange" to "aaa", it works.
When I update "apple"  to "bbb", it also works.
But, when I update "mango" to "ccc", "aaa" and "bbb" also change to "ccc".

How do I fix? If I refresh the page after updating data, it work fine. But I don't want to refresh the page.

catagorie.sql

```
CREATE TABLE `catagorie` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `item` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `kyat` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `catagorie` (`id`, `item`, `kyat`) VALUES
(1, 'orange', '100'),
(2, 'apple', '200'),
(3, 'mango', '300');
```

catagorie.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Catalog</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="dark">
            <div id="box">
                <input type="text" id="item" placeholder="Item"><hr><br>
                <input type="text" id="kyat" placeholder="Kyat"><hr><br>
                <input type="submit" value="Update" id="update">
            </div>
        </div>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Item</th>
                <th>Kyat</th>
                <th style="text-align: center;">Option</th>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>       
        <script src="app.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

api.php

```
<?php

    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");

    mysqli_select_db($conn, "shop");

    $action = $_REQUEST['action'];

    switch ($action) {

        case 'show':
            show();
            break;

        case 'update':
            update();
            break;
        
        default:
            break;
    }

    function show() {

        global $conn;

        $numb = 5;

        $arr  = array();

        $start = $_REQUEST['start'];

        $query = 'SELECT * FROM catagorie LIMIT ?, ?';

        $stmt = $conn -> prepare($query);
        $stmt -> bind_param('ii', $start, $numb);
        $stmt -> execute();

        $result = $stmt -> get_result();

        while($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()) { $arr[] = $row; }

        echo json_encode($arr);
    }

    function update() {

        global $conn;

        $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
        $item = $_REQUEST['item'];
        $kyat = $_REQUEST['kyat'];

        $query = 'UPDATE catagorie SET item = ?, kyat = ? WHERE id = ?';

        $stmt = $conn -> prepare($query);
        $stmt -> bind_param('sii', $item, $kyat, $id);
        $stmt -> execute();

        echo json_encode(array("msg" => 1));
    }

?>
```

app.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.get("api.php", { action: "show", start: 0 }, function(res) {

        $.each(res, function(key, value) {

            var upd = $("<a>", { href: "#" }).html(" [ update ] ").click(function() {

                $("#item").val(value.item);
                $("#kyat").val(value.kyat);

                $("#dark").show();

                $("#update").click(function() {

                    var item = $("#item").val();
                    var kyat = $("#kyat").val();
                    var note = $("#note").val();

                    $.get("api.php", { action: "update", id: id, item: item, kyat: kyat }, function(msg) {

                        if(msg.msg == 1) {

                            $("#dark").hide();
                            //location.reload();
                        }

                    }, "json");

                });

            });

            var id = value.id;
            var item = $("<td>").append(value.item);
            var kyat = $("<td>").append(value.kyat);
            var opti = $("<td style='text-align: center;'>").append(upd);

            var tr = $("<tr>").data("id", id).append(item).append(kyat).append(opti);

            tr.appendTo("table");

        });

    }, "json");

});
```

style.css

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 70%;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

th, td {
    width: 30%;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: left
}

th { background: lightgreen; }

td a { text-decoration: none; }

tr:nth-child(odd) { background: grey; }

tr:nth-child(even) { background: lightgrey; }

div#dark {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
}

div#box {
    width: 600px;
    margin: 45px auto;
    padding: 20px;  
    background: lightgrey;
    border: 3px solid purple;
}

input#item, input#kyat {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    padding: 5px;
    background: transparent;
}

hr { width: 100%; border: 1px solid purple; }
```

Comment: can you please make your update button type="button"
 ```<input type="button" value="Update" id="update">```

Comment: Ya. I made. But, same result.

Comment: Start by inspecting the actual request in browser dev tools network tab and see exactly what is sent and that is is what you expect. Need to narrow down where the specific problem is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(...).click(fn)` adds `fn` as a handler for the click event. It does not replace any existing handlers. In your code,

```
...

$("#update").click(function() {
  ....
});

...
```

is adding a new handler each time someone clicks on the `update` button on any row. The problem is that since the old handlers aren't being replaced, both the new handler `fn` and the old `fn`s will get called when the button is clicked. Reloading the page will fix the issue since the handlers are reset after you reload the page.

The possible solutions would be

1. Remove the old handler before adding a new one
2. Add only 1 handler, i.e. move `$("#update").click(function() {` outside of the `$.each` block

Answer (score 1):

Try to do this using $.ajax() method that is used to perform an AJAX (asynchronous HTTP) request.

```
$("button").click(function(){
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'api.php',
    data: {
        yourdataname: $("#elementID").val(),
        yourdataname2: $("#elementID2").val(),
    },

 success: function(result){
   //this success bolck works only if your requst success. 
    $("#div1").html(result);
  },
 error:function(error){
  //this error bolck works only if your requst has error.
    console.log(error);
}
   });
});
```

Comment: `$.get()` is a shorthand method of `$.ajax` and OP is requesting json which you are not here. You are treating response as html. Beyond that how would this solve the problem mentioned in question? Solution seems completely irrelevant to the problem